# How to allow user to search through results of a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, html

So I've done the following:
I've done a fetch request to pull a list of 10 individuals. I've set up arrays for the three elements from the list that I want the end user to be able to search through. So what I'm really wanting is for the end user to be able to click in the search bar, type in an email address, and have that data (specific to the email address) be displayed in the boxes.

I'm a bit lost on what to enter in the JavaScript to do this. Any help appreciated. I've put some code below followed by the jsfiddle.

```
 HTML:
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="search" id="myInput" placeholder="Searchbox" 
    onclick="searchFunction()" />
  <div class="container">
    <table id='myTable'>
       <tr>
          <td id="one">ID</td>
          <td id="two">Name</td>
          <td id="three">Website</td>
          <td id="four">4</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td id="five">5</td>
         <td id="six">6</td>
         <td id="seven">7</td>
         <td id="eight">8</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Then for the JS:

```
 let items =document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
 let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 let receivedData = [];
 let identifier = [];
 let name = [];
 let website = [];

   fetch("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
     .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
      return;
    }
    response.json().then(function(data) { //data is present in array
      for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      receivedData.push(data[i]);
      console.log(receivedData);

      for (let j=0; j<receivedData.length; j++)
      name.push(receivedData[j].name)
      console.log(name);

      for (let n=0; n<receivedData.length; n++)
      identifier.push(receivedData[n].id)
      console.log(identifier);

      for (let x=0; x<receivedData.length; x++)
      website.push(receivedData[x].website)
      console.log(website);
    });
  }
)
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
});
```

Again the results are populating in the fetch it's just getting them as a search option in HTML that I've hit a wall.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakewayne/tw367o98/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to prefetch data and store them in global variables, I think the remaining process is quite simple:

1. The user inputs something in the search box.
2. Get associated data based on the input.
3. Update those data in the table.

The skeleton may look like this:

```
input.addEventListener('input', onInput, false);

function onInput(event) {
  const searchString = event.target.value;
  const data = getAssociatedData(searchString);
  updateTable(data);
}

function getAssociatedData(searchString) {
  // return associated data based on the search string
}

function updateTable(data) {
  // update the table through DOM api
}
```

**Note:**

- You should listen for `input` event rather than `click` event.
- The whole `response.json().then()` must be returned in the first `then()`, or any error occurred in that promise chain won't be caught by your `catch()`.